# mysqlでUPDATE文のWHERE句で日付比較を行うとincorrect datetime valueが発生する

Tags: mysql

UPDATE文のWHERE句で日付の比較を行うとincorrect datetime valueが発生してしまいます。以下実行SQLです。

```
UPDATE SHAIN
SET
  COLUMN1 = COLUMN2
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(TAISHABI), '%Y%m%d')
```

SELECT文で同じ条件で実行するとエラーが発生せず、実行されます。
エラーは、DATETIME型に正しい値を入れてくださいという意味だと思うのですが、
COLUMN1とCOLUMN2はどちらもVARCHAR型となっており、DATETIME型はwhere句のTAISHABIだけとなります。
エラーを解消するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`TAISHABI` が `'0000-00-00'` であるようなレコードが存在している状態で、 [`sql_mode` の `NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) を有効化して `update`や`select`を行えば質問文のような状況になります。
("Incorrect datetime value" のメッセージと共に、エラーとなっている値も出力されていないでしょうか)

この場合は、[`sql_mode` 設定](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) で `NO_ZERO_DATE` を有効化しなければ `update` も通るでしょう。

Comment: sql_mode設定の「NO_ZERO_DATE」でupdateすることができました。ありがとうございます。